# Is the Japanese か more rounded than the Chinese 力?

Tags: kanji, hiragana

Is the Japanese か more rounded than the Chinese 力 ?

It seems the Chinese character has a sharper corner there on the first stroke while the Japanese kanji seems to curve around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. か is more rounded than 力.

か (ka)： is Hiragana character.

力 (ちから - Chikara)： "power", it is Kanji character.

か and 力 are both Japanese. And 力 is also a kanji (Chinese character). But か is not a Chinese character, and it is not a kanji, it is a hiragana letter in Japanese.

They are different! :D

Comment: Also can't forget カ the katakana character, which looks pretty much the same as the kanji.